# Commit blocks using spring-amqp and rabbitmq when disk_size_limit threshold is reached

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

We are using rabbitmq 3.0.1 on CentOS 6, and as a client Spring spring-rabbit version 1.1.2.RELEASE. (I know these aren't the latest versions, see later).

We send messages to `rabbitmq` via this client. These messages are initiated via an external rest call. Someone else calls our web service updates the database and sends the amqp message. I would like to be informed if `rabbitmq` blocks the client - for instance if the `disk_free_limit` threshold is reached.

Importantly, I would like to be informed in the *same thread* as that processing the web request, so that I can rollback the transaction.

Our web service can also update a database (within a transaction obviously). Normally, this works fine. However, under certain circumstances, rabbitmq can block our web server - the most obvious being when the disk_free_limit is reached. This blocks the web server Thread, indefinitely. The external caller of the web service will obviously time out after a sensible period, but the thread in our web service doesn't - it stays around, and keeps the resources, and importantly the transaction open.

The web server is blocking the thread because it is transactional. It isn't the initial message which is blocking, it is the commit. I assume that rabbitmq is blocking because it can't persist it or something like that. The thread is blocking until rabbitmq sends the commit ok message back. The bit of code is deep within the rabbitmq implementation - [com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/3.3.4/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/ChannelN.java?av=f#1055)

```
public Tx.CommitOk More ...txCommit() throws IOException
{
  return (Tx.CommitOk) exnWrappingRpc(new Tx.Commit()).getMethod();
}
```

and this eventually calls the following method from [com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client/3.3.4/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/AMQChannel.java#AMQChannel.BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply%28%29)

```
public T More ...getReply() throws ShutdownSignalException
{
    return _blocker.uninterruptibleGetValue();
}
```

The preferable solution for this would be some sort of timeout on the `txCommit` - then I could throw an exception and fail the web service with a 500 or whatever. I can't find any way of doing this.

What I have found is:

1. [addBlockedListener](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.3.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.3.5/com/rabbitmq/client/Connection.html#addBlockedListener(com.rabbitmq.client.BlockedListener)) - this adds a listener on a message sent by rabbitmq when this it is blocked. This is good, but the message will is treated by another thread - so I can't fail the web service. Using this I can at least log the fact that rabbitmq is blocked, through syslog or whatever. However, this isn't available on the version that we run - we would have to upgrade to the latest. We would prefer not to do this because of the testing it would imply.
2. [setConnectionTimeout(int)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.3.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.3.5/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html#setConnectionTimeout(int)) - this sets the connection timeout for the initial connection to rabbitmq. This doesn't apply in my case, because rabbitmq is up and running and accepts the connection.
3. [AmqpTemplate.setReplyTimeout()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest_ga/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#setReplyTimeout(long)) - as shown above, this reply timeout does not apply to the commit.

I fully understand that this situation (`disk_free_limit` threshold is breached) is a situation which should not occur in a production system. However, I would like to be able to cope nicely with this situation so that my application behaves nicely when one of its components (rabbitmq) has a problem.

So, what other options do I have? Is there any way, short of rewriting portions of the spring amqp client or removing the transactionality of doing what I want?

Comment: Hi Matthew, Just wondering if you ever managed to figure out a work around for this? Thanks